# how to add empty bracket in array of string

Tags: scala

Given

```
val ss = List((1, 2, "r"), (2, 2, "r"), (1, 4, "r"), (1, 5, "p"), (1, 6, "s"))
```

then

```
val pp = ss.toArray.groupBy(_._2).toSeq.sortBy(_._1).toList.map(f => {
  f._2.map {
    case (x, y, z) => if (z == "r") { // when z == "s" || z =="p" empty bracket will be added
      s"$x,$y,$z"
    } else {
      ""
    }
  }
})
```

serialises with `Json.toJson` to

```
[
  [
    "1,2,r",
    "2,2,r"
  ],
  [
    "1,3,r"
  ],
  [""],
  [""]
]
```

but JSON output should look like this

```
[
  [
    "1,2,r",
    "2,2,r"
  ],
  [
    "1,3,r"
  ],
  [],
  []
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` + `Option` as following

```scala
val ss = List((1, 2, "r"), (2, 2, "r"), (1, 4, "r"), (1, 5, "p"), (1, 6, "s"))
val pp = ss
  .groupBy(_._2)
  .toSeq
  .sortBy(_._1)
  .map(_._2.flatMap {
    case (x, y, z) if z == "r" =>
      Option(s"$x,$y,$z")
    case _ => 
      None
  })

println(pp)
```

```
List(List(1,2,r, 2,2,r), List(1,4,r), List(), List())
```

Comment: Thanks, for the answer have tried your code, pp I am getting is seq[List[String]], and I want  answer in Array[Array[String]]. so, I converted pp to this Array[Array[String]]. But, only one empty bracket was added and 2nd one was not added.when I represented this to json format.  Json.toJson(Array[Array[String]])

Comment: @varsha `Array` is a Java type not a Scala type, so typically Scala code would use `List` or `Vector` for this sort of thing.

Comment: okay, but can you tell me why only one empty bracket is added and not the second one in the list.

Answer (score 3):

The simple solution is to use `collect` rather than `map` in the inner code. You can also remove some of the type conversions without changing the logic:

```
ss.groupBy(_._2).toList.sortBy(_._1).map {
  _._2.collect {
    case (x, y, z) if z == "r" =>
      s"$x,$y,$z"
  }
}
```

---

If you want `Array[Array[String]]` (as suggested in comments) do this:

```
ss.groupBy(_._2).toArray.sortBy(_._1).map {
  _._2.toArray.collect {
    case (x, y, z) if z == "r" =>
      s"$x,$y,$z"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Note the difference between empty `List`

```
scala> List.empty[String]
val res0: List[String] = List()

scala> .length
val res1: Int = 0
```

and `List` of one element that happens to be empty `String`

```
scala> List("")
val res2: List[String] = List("")

scala> .length
val res3: Int = 1
```

Perhaps it is clearer to see that empty string `""` represents an actual value like so

```
scala> List(new String())
val res4: List[String] = List("")

scala> .length
val res5: Int = 1
```